# In openshift Nodejs Socket.io responce 200 Ok, But console.log value not visible. my socket is working?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openshift

created index.js (server)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

///creating server
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, { origins:'http://nodejs-atnodejs.rhcloud.com:8000' });
```

below is remaining code
 Routing to index.html page

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('in socket---' + res);
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});
///socket connection
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('chatmessage', function (msg) {
        io.emit('chatmessage', msg);
        console.log('in socket---' + data);
    });
});
/// Listen to Openshift port
server.listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT, process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP);
```

created index.html(client)

```
src="http://nodejs-atnodejs.rhcloud.com:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js   
     var socket = io.connect('http://nodejs-atnodejs.rhcloud.com:8000');
       console.log('this is index page');
        socket.on('chatmessage', function (data) {
            console.log('chatmessage---' + data);
            socket.emit('chatmessage', { my: 'data' });
        });
```

When accessed from browser:
[image: when accessed from browser]

```
Problem is not getting "console.log('chatmessage---' + data);" which is inside the socket.. 

and keep on getting xhr-polling../t=xxxxx responses..

is my socket working properly?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your browser and server code is listening for an event of 'chatmessage' after connection either your browser or server should be emitting the event first and than the other should be listening such as...

```
// server
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('chatmessage', /*some data*/);
});

//client
socket.on('chatmessage', function (data) {
  console.log('chatmessage---' + data);
});
```

Comment: thanks,but its not working.here is my complete code https://github.com/varund29/openshift/blob/master/index.html  and https://github.com/varund29/openshift/blob/master/index.js please let me know if any thing wrong in that.

Comment: either way your code will need to emit a chat message event for your event listeners to receive it. You have to 'on' events waiting for something to emit that type.

Comment: that's perfect checkout out their socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val()); and then  socket.on('chat message', function(msg) their browser emits the event after connection

Comment: yes, your correct..the code exactly as is..but its not working. and even its not showing log messages and  keep on getting xhr-polling../t=xxxxx responses..